# NetBeans Gui not showing up

Tags: java, swing

The GUI is not showing up, and when i run it from CMD it doesn't give me an error. In CMD, i type `javac NewJPanel.java`, then `java NewJPanel` and then it doesn't pop up any window.

```
 /**
 *
 * @author Kevin
 */
 import java.awt.*;
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

NewJPanel(){

       setVisible(true);
       setSize(300,400);
    }
/**
 * Creates new form NewJPanel
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NewJPanel();
}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    lblDH1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblDM1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblDN1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblDH2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblDM2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblDN2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblDH3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDH3 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDN2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane5 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDM3 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane6 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDN3 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane7 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDN1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane8 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfTV1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    btnCalcular = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane10 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea10 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane11 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfTV3 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane12 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfPH = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    lblDM3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblDN3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblTV1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblTV3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblPH = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane13 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDH1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane14 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDM1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane15 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDH2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane16 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfDM2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    lblTN = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane19 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tfTN = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    lblDH1.setText("Deportdos Hombres Vuelo #1");
    lblDH1.setName("lblDH1"); // NOI18N

    lblDM1.setText("Deportados Mujeres Vuelo #1");
    lblDM1.setName("lblDM1"); // NOI18N

    lblDN1.setText("Deportados Ninos Vuelo #1");
    lblDN1.setName("lblDN1"); // NOI18N

    lblDH2.setText("Deportados Hombres Vuelo #2");
    lblDH2.setName("lblDH2"); // NOI18N

    lblDM2.setText("Deportados Mujeres Vuelo #2");
    lblDM2.setName("lblDM2"); // NOI18N

    lblDN2.setText("Deportados Ninos Vuelo #2");
    lblDN2.setName("lblDN2"); // NOI18N

    lblDH3.setText("Deportados Hombres Vuelo #3");

    jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDH3.setColumns(20);
    tfDH3.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tfDH3);

    jScrollPane4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDN2.setColumns(20);
    tfDN2.setRows(5);
    tfDN2.setName("tfDN2"); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane4.setViewportView(tfDN2);

    jScrollPane5.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDM3.setColumns(20);
    tfDM3.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane5.setViewportView(tfDM3);

    jScrollPane6.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDN3.setColumns(20);
    tfDN3.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane6.setViewportView(tfDN3);

    jScrollPane7.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDN1.setColumns(20);
    tfDN1.setRows(5);
    tfDN1.setName("tfDN1"); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane7.setViewportView(tfDN1);

    jScrollPane8.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfTV1.setEditable(false);
    tfTV1.setColumns(20);
    tfTV1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane8.setViewportView(tfTV1);

    btnCalcular.setText("Calcular");
    btnCalcular.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCalcularActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel10.setText("Llegaron menos de 8 ninos en el vuelo 1");

    jLabel11.setText("Llegaron menos de 8 ninos en el vuelo 2");

    jLabel12.setText("Llegaron menos de 8 ninos en el vuelo 3");

    jScrollPane10.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    jTextArea10.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea10.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea10.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane10.setViewportView(jTextArea10);

    jScrollPane11.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfTV3.setEditable(false);
    tfTV3.setColumns(20);
    tfTV3.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane11.setViewportView(tfTV3);

    jScrollPane12.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfPH.setEditable(false);
    tfPH.setColumns(20);
    tfPH.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane12.setViewportView(tfPH);

    lblDM3.setText("Deportados Mujeres Vuelo #3");

    lblDN3.setText("Deportados Ninos Vuelo #3");

    lblTV1.setText("Total Deportados Vuelo #1");

    lblTV3.setText("Total Deportados Vuelo #3");

    lblPH.setText("Porcentaje de Deportados");

    jScrollPane13.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDH1.setColumns(20);
    tfDH1.setRows(5);
    tfDH1.setName("tfDH1"); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane13.setViewportView(tfDH1);

    jScrollPane14.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDM1.setColumns(20);
    tfDM1.setRows(5);
    tfDM1.setName("tfDM1"); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane14.setViewportView(tfDM1);

    jScrollPane15.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDH2.setColumns(20);
    tfDH2.setRows(5);
    tfDH2.setName("tfDH1"); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane15.setViewportView(tfDH2);

    jScrollPane16.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfDM2.setColumns(20);
    tfDM2.setRows(5);
    tfDM2.setName("tfDM2"); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane16.setViewportView(tfDM2);

    lblTN.setText("Grupo con Mayor Numero de Deportados");

    jScrollPane19.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 96));

    tfTN.setEditable(false);
    tfTN.setColumns(20);
    tfTN.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane19.setViewportView(tfTN);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(lblTN)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel12)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel11)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel10)))
                            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 201, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(btnCalcular, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(97, 97, 97))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lblDH1)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblDM1)
                                .addComponent(lblDH2)
                                .addComponent(lblDM2)
                                .addComponent(lblDN2)
                                .addComponent(lblDN1)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblPH)
                                .addComponent(lblTV3)
                                .addComponent(lblTV1)
                                .addComponent(lblDM3)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblDH3)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblDN3)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 184, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel15)
            .addGap(112, 112, 112)
            .addComponent(btnCalcular, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(88, 88, 88))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(24, 24, 24)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblDH1)
                .addComponent(lblDH3))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(lblDM1)
                                .addComponent(lblDM3))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblDN1)
                        .addComponent(lblDN3))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblDH2)
                        .addComponent(lblTV1)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addGap(91, 91, 91)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel12)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lblDM2)
                                .addComponent(lblTV3)))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(lblDN2)
                                        .addComponent(lblPH))
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
            .addComponent(lblTN)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(121, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnCalcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    btnCalcularActionPerformed(evt);
    if (evt.getSource()== btnCalcular)
    {
        Migracion dia = new Migracion();
        Vuelo vuelo1 = new Vuelo();
        Vuelo vuelo2 = new Vuelo();
        Vuelo vuelo3 = new Vuelo();

        int a=0;
        int b=0;
        int c=0;
        int d=0;
        int e=0;
        int f=0;
        int g=0;
        int h=0;
        int i=0;
        a=Integer.parseInt(tfDH1.getText());
        b=Integer.parseInt(tfDM1.getText());
        c=Integer.parseInt(tfDN1.getText());
        d=Integer.parseInt(tfDH2.getText());
        e=Integer.parseInt(tfDM2.getText());
        f=Integer.parseInt(tfDN2.getText());
        g=Integer.parseInt(tfDH3.getText());
        h=Integer.parseInt(tfDM3.getText());
        i=Integer.parseInt(tfDN3.getText());


        dia.setMigra1(a, b, c);
        vuelo1.setNHombres(a);
        vuelo1.setNMujeres(b);
        vuelo1.setNNinos(c);

        dia.setMigra2(d, e, f);
        vuelo2.setNHombres(d);
        vuelo2.setNMujeres(e);
        vuelo2.setNNinos(f);

        dia.setMigra3(g, h, i);
        vuelo3.setNHombres(g);
        vuelo3.setNMujeres(h);
        vuelo3.setNNinos(i);

        int dm=0;
        int dh=0;
        int dn=0;
        String z1;
        String y;
        dh=vuelo1.getNNinos();
        dm=vuelo1.getNHombres();
        dn=vuelo1.getNMujeres();
        z1=vuelo1.total(dh, dm, dn);
        y=vuelo3.total(g, h, i);
        jTextArea10.setText(String.valueOf(z1));
        tfTV3.setText(String.valueOf(y));

        String a1="", a2="", a3="";
        a1=vuelo1.advertencia(c);
        a2=vuelo2.advertencia(f);
        a2=vuelo3.advertencia(i);

        if (a1!=" "){
        jLabel10.setText("Llegaron Menos de 8 Ninos en el Vuelo 1");
        }
        if (a2!=" "){
        jLabel11.setText("Llegaron Menos de 8 Ninos en el Vuelo 1");
        }
        if (a3!=" "){
        jLabel12.setText("Llegaron Menos de 8 Ninos en el Vuelo 1");
        }

        tfPH.setText(dia.getPorcentaje());
        tfTN.setText(dia.getMayoria());
    }
}                                           


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnCalcular;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane10;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane11;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane12;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane13;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane14;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane15;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane16;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane19;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane5;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane6;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane7;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane8;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea10;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDH1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDH2;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDH3;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDM1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDM2;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDM3;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDN1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDN2;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDN3;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblPH;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTN;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTV1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTV3;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDH1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDH2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDH3;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDM1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDM2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDM3;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDN1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDN2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfDN3;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfPH;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfTN;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfTV1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea tfTV3;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I got the code from NetBeans gui builder, and pasted it into notepad++, then i added the listeners and some code. Also i deleted the package line from it.

Comment: For me, the real lesson here is to avoid using a code-generation tool, such as NetBeans GUI code generation, before understanding the underlying GUI library, here Swing, and you can learn how Swing works by going through the Swing tutorials, whose link you can find here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). Note that I am differentiating between NetBeans code-generation and the NetBeans IDE.